# Android - Custom dialog showing weird layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making a custom dialog from a layout file

Java code:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CategoryActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.content_privacy_dialog);
TextView dialog_title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
dialog_title.setText(getString(R.string.nav_privacy));
dialog.show();
```

Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dialogBg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:text="About"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting this result:

[image]

**How can I hide the white space on top and the blue bar?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CategoryActivity.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.content_privacy_dialog);
TextView dialog_title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
dialog_title.setText(getString(R.string.nav_privacy));
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using simple Dialog i would recomend you to use Material Dialogs. You can get help from this link 
https://material.google.com/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs